# Issue with a single razor view accessing two models (ASP.NET MVC3)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

View(Index.chtml) is returning 0 rows while accessing two models in the view. Please see the code below. I am new to ASP.NET and I am still learning. I tried to debug and I see the table data is not being passed to correctly. Please help

```
================================================================================
Controller: (OrganizationCodesController.cs)
================================================================================
namespace MvcProject.Controllers
{
    public class OrganizationCodesController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /OrganizationCodes/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<TABLE_CODES> temp_codes = new List<TABLE_CODES>();
            List<TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS> temp_organizations = new List<TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS>();

            var viewModel = new OrganizationCodesModel(temp_codes, temp_organizations);
            return View(viewModel);

        }
    }       
============================================================================
Model: (OrganizationCodesModel.cs)
============================================================================
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;

namespace MvcProject.Models
{


    public class OrganizationCodesModel 
    {
        public List<TABLE_CODES> TABLE_CODES { get; set; }
        public List<TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS> TABLE_CODES { get; set; }

        public OrganizationCodesModel(List<TABLE_CODES> _codes, List<TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS> _organizations)
        {
            TABLE_CODES = _codes;
            TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS = _organizations;
        }   
    }
}
========================================================================
View: (Index.chtml)
========================================================================
@model MvcProject.Models.OrganizationCodesModel

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
        <th>
            ORGANIZATION_NAME
        </th>
        <th>
            RANK
        </th>
        <th>
            LEVEL
        </th>
</thead>    
<tbody> 
@foreach (var item in Model.TABLE_CODES) {
    <tr>
        <td>
        @foreach (var item_1 in Model.TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS)
        {
            if (item.LOCATION == item_1.ID)
            {
            @item1.NAME
                break;
            }
        }    
        </td>
        <td>
        @item.RANK
        </td>
        <td>
        @item.LEVEL
        </td>
    </tr>
}   
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's because you never put anything in the lists.

Comment: The reason you see 0 rows is because you're creating two empty lists. What are you expecting, trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to create a view with a data generated from accessing two models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modiy your `Model Class`  like this:

```
public class OrganizationCodesModel
{
    public List<TABLE_CODES> listTABLE_CODES { get; set; }
    public List<TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS> listTABLE_ORGANIZATIONS { get; set; }
}
```

I have also added text "list" as prefix to the name of the list to distinguish it from the class name otherwise both list name and class name are same.

Ok Now you have to also modify your  `Index action method` like this:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        OrganizationCodesModel model = new OrganizationCodesModel();

        List<TABLE_CODES>listCodes = new List<TABLE_CODES> {
          new TABLE_CODES {LOCATION = 1, RANK = 1, LEVEL  =1},
          new TABLE_CODES{LOCATION = 2, RANK = 3, LEVEL = 12345}
        };
        List<TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS> listOrganisation = new List<TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS> {
          new TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS {ID = 1,NAME="ABC"},
          new TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS{ID = 2,NAME="XYZ"}
        };

        model.ListTABLE_CODES = listCodes;
        model.ListTABLE_ORGANIZATIONS = listOrganisation;
        return View(model);
    }
```

and in your `View` just replace your List name like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.listTABLE_CODES )
@foreach (var item_1 in Model.listTABLE_ORGANIZATIONS )
```

That is all. Now you will be able to see your output like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jitender. Best part is I learnt what I was missing from Raphael response and I learnt how the problem should be approached and solved from yours. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome Archer, I am glad that my answer also helped you. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
List<TABLE_CODES> temp_codes = new List<TABLE_CODES>();
List<TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS> temp_organizations = new List<TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS>();

var viewModel = new OrganizationCodesModel(temp_codes, temp_organizations);
```

your instanciating two empty lists...

you should put something in your lists !

something like

```
List<TABLE_CODES> temp_codes = GetTempCodesFromSomewhere();
```

or

```
List<TABLE_CODES> temp_codes = new List<TABLE_CODES> {
   new TABLE_CODES {LOCATION = 1, RANK = 1, LEVEL  =1},
   new TABLE_CODES{LOCATION = 2, RANK = 3, LEVEL = 12345}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was not sure how to fill those lists. For example, in the above code, TABLE_CODES and TABLE_ORGANIZATIONS are the tables that have the real data

Comment: Well. They are the "object" representaiton of your tables. So you have certainly a way to fill these object with Data, don't you ?

Comment: yes I could understand that from your response on filling those objects. I will give it a try. Thanks Raphael!

Comment: I used your suggested second approach for filling the list: List<TABLE_CODES> temp_codes= new List<TABLE_CODES> { new TABLE_CODES() }; //I want entire table "TABLE_CODES" data to be filled into temp_codes //  It did not help I still see table with no values